# Convert T to IList

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method like the one below. And I check that the incomming parameter is a IList but how do I convert the parameter to a IList?

```
public T myMethod<T>(T parameter)
{
    //check if the parameter is a list
    if (parameter IList && parameter.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
       //How can I convert my parameter to an IList that supports IEnumerable interface?
       // So i can do the following
       foreach (var listObject in parameter)
       {
           // Do stuff
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your if statement work? Do you mean: if (parameter is IList... ? If yes, then all you have to do is cast it.

Comment: A simple cast will work but you can only get the contents as `object` references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `(parameter as IList)`.

I assume you don't want to just restrict the parameter to an `IList` in all cases.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the answer of Marnix is correct, you need a where, or else why you would need a generic type T?

However, here there are 5 different possibilities you have.

Possibility 1:

```
    public void xxx<T>(IList<T> parameter)
    {
        foreach (var listObject in parameter)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Possibility 2:

```
    public void xxx<T>(T parameter) where T : IList
    {
        foreach (var listObject in parameter)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Possibility 3:

```
    public void xxx<T>(T parameter)
    {
        IList list = parameter as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var listObject in list)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Possibility 4:

```
    public void xxx(IList parameter)
    {
        foreach (var listObject in list)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Possibility 5:

```
    public void xxx(object parameter)
    {
        IList list = parameter as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var listObject in list)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Another big question: Why are you using IList? if you need just to enumerate, use IEnumerable and IEnumerable of T, it will allow you to use more types and have more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

I would do like this:

```
public T myMethod<T>(T parameter) where T : IEnumerable
```

then you don't need to cast or convert anything, you can directly do your `foreach` :)

Comment: or even public T myMethod(IEnumerable parameter)

Comment: Why would you not just make the parameter an `IEnumerable` (or `IList`)?

Answer (score 2):

I think this piece of code will make sure that your parameter is always an

```
public T myMethod<T>(T parameter) where T:IList
{
    // bla
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
public IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> parameter)
{
   ....
}
```

Or `IList<T>` if you prefer.

The you can just use your parameter knowing it's an IEnumerable. It's the least complicated way and it matches how the framework does it.